# .live not working after ajax $.post

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use .live to ensure that my elements respond to click events even after an ajax call (in my case i use $.post) so for example **after my ajax call** i do this:

```
$('.link').live({
    click: function() {
        alert('testing');
    }
});
```

it doesn't working. Only if i switch it to using a normal click event like this:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    alert('testing);
}
```

it works. But the thing is the **$link** only appears to the user only after each ajax call and is the one actually making the ajax call. So if i use a normal click event, it will only work once after the first ajax call (i bind the event after the first ajax call) which shows the $link for the first time.

After the $link is shown for the first time, and is clicked by the user for the first time, it will show a list of items including the $link again at the bottom. However, this time it doesn't work anymore because i am still only binding the click event without using .live.

How do i make it so that .live works, which will enable the link to work everytime after N number of times of clicks?

**Edited:** Change $list to using a selector. Sorry about the unclear information before. I am in fact using a selector for using .live . I am actually trying to provide a 'View more' functionality. So after a user enters something in a textbox, the search results appear (via ajax) and the 'View more' link appears at the bottom. When the user clicks it, more relevant search results will be appended to the list and another 'View more' link will be at the bottom of the list again. However, this time it doesn't work anymore because i can't get the .live to work with it.

Comment: Obvious question - but I assume you've checked your version of jQuery? That version of .live only works with 1.4.3 and later

Comment: Can you show us how you are getting the value for $link?

Comment: @Prescott i am using jQuery 1.6.1 at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using event bubbling instead. What i did was instead of using .live(), i did this:

```
$('.linkParent').click(function(event) {

    $tgt = $(event.target);

    if ($tgt.attr('class')=='link') { alert('works now!'); }

});
```

Such that **$('.link')** is always inside **$('.linkParent')** and the ajax call is always only loading stuff inside of **$('.linkParent')**.

Comment: That's exactly what the `delegate` method does, which is a variant of the `live` method. If that works, either `live` or `delegate` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like I always do it like:

```
$(".class").live("click", function () {
    //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a selector when you specify the `live` delegate. Example:

```
$('.SomeClass').live(...
```

This will bind the event to the document, where it will check the origin of the event. If the origin matches the selector, the event handler is triggered.

You have to use a selector when you bind the `live` delegate, you can't use any other method of traversing the DOM to find the elements, as the selector is evaluated when the event happens, not when the delegate is bound.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. Edited my original question to make it more clear now